# Autoconf: Testing whether gcc -m32 works AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG doesn't solve it

Tags: gcc, 32-bit, autoconf

I would like to tests to see if a system has full support for gcc -m32. I tried using AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-m32], ..., ...).  That test doesn't do what I would like it to do.  It seems to test whether -m32 is a valid option to gcc, **NOT** that it actually can compile a code.

I know that if I test -m33 then AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG correctly says that there is no option -m33 as expected.

On this particular system compiling a simple hello world program does the following:

```
$ gcc -m32 -c hello.c

 In file included from /usr/include/features.h:385,
                  from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                  from hello.c:1:
 /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
```

and returns a non-zero status.  This non-zero status is what I like to be able to test for.

Comment: Are you using the `[SUCCESS]`, `[FAILURE]`, `[INPUT]` arguments?

Comment: yes I am. See my answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to the problem.  Basically, I took the AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG test and change the internals to use AC_RUN_IFELSE instead of AC_COMPILE_IFELSE.  I have changed the name to AX_TEST_COMPILE_FLAG and here is how use it:

```
AX_TEST_COMPILE_FLAG([-m32],[HAVE_32BIT=yes],[HAVE_32BIT=no])
```

and here is the definition:

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_TEST_COMPILE_FLAG],
[AC_PREREQ(2.64)dnl for _AC_LANG_PREFIX and AS_VAR_IF
AS_VAR_PUSHDEF([CACHEVAR] [ax_cv_check_[]_AC_LANG_ABBREV[]flags_$4_$1])dnl
AC_CACHE_CHECK([whether _AC_LANG compiler can build and run with $1], CACHEVAR, [
  ax_check_save_flags=$[]_AC_LANG_PREFIX[]FLAGS
  _AC_LANG_PREFIX[]FLAGS="$[]_AC_LANG_PREFIX[]FLAGS $4 $1"
  AC_RUN_IFELSE([m4_default([$5],[AC_LANG_PROGRAM()])],
    [AS_VAR_SET(CACHEVAR,[yes])],
    [AS_VAR_SET(CACHEVAR,[no])])
  _AC_LANG_PREFIX[]FLAGS=$ax_check_save_flags])
AS_VAR_IF(CACHEVAR,yes,
  [m4_default([$2], :)],
  [m4_default([$3], :)])
AS_VAR_POPDEF([CACHEVAR])dnl
])dnl AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAGS
```